# writing if/else to avoid parserError saying document is empty

Tags: python, django

I'm using python goose extractor(function to extract data when url is submitted) and very sometimes I get ParserError Saying Document is empty. I'm guessing it means the url I submit is empty? the thing is I just want to avoid this error since it's very unlikely I get this error.
Currently my code looks like this

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    if article.top_image is None:
        return DEFAULT 

    else:
        if article.top_image.src is None:
          return DEFAULT
        else:
            resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
            return article.top_image.src
```

how should I add else statement to avoid the parser Error,,,if it's try/catch I can go catch parserError but not sure what to do for else...I'm using if/else because I heard its faster.

Comment: try/catch and if/else have two separate use cases... are you able to continue at all if you get a parser error?

Comment: You can make a common try/catch for both if,else and you also can create separate for both. It depends on you. it will work in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to catch exception is to use try/except. Something like:

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    try:
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        if article.top_image is None:
            return DEFAULT 

        else:
            if article.top_image.src is None:
              return DEFAULT
            else:
                resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
                return article.top_image.src
    except ParseError:
        handle_exception()
```

As for speed, no `if`-`else` is not faster in these kind of occasions. There's should be (almost) cost in using `try`-`except` as long as exception doesn't happen (and as you pointed out it doesn't happen often).

Even in the case where exception actually happens it isn't very expensive. It is considered the preferred error handling mechanism in python and it's used quite liberally in the libraries.

One thing to note when you catch an exception (regardless of language) you should actually handle the error properly. If you can't handle the error it's most often correct to just let it propagate up. There's almost never proper to just swallow the exception silently.

What you **could** do however is to re-raise if you find out you can't handle it, or if you just want to print out some information:

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    try:
        article = g.extract(url=url)
        if article.top_image is None:
            return DEFAULT 

        else:
            if article.top_image.src is None:
              return DEFAULT
            else:
                resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
                return article.top_image.src
    except ParseError:
        if can_handle():
            handle_exception()
        else:
            print("Oops, couldn't handle exception: url={0}".format(url))
            raise
```

Comment: Thank you "S" as skyking

Comment: @Sayse You're correct, exception handler should normally handle the exception or re-raise if it can't be handled. I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: what does handle_exception() do? will inserting try and catch method decrease its speed extracting?its already slow right now

Comment: @mikebraa It's a place holder for doing whatever handling of the exception that's proper. As pointed out it should not have any (significant) impact on speed.

Comment: thanks, lastly when i deploy do I need to use other keyword instead of print?  for             print("Oops, couldn't handle exception: url={0}".format(url))